# Check if image exists on remote server before downloading

Tags: php, file-get-contents, file-exists

Im trying to download images from remote server, resize and then save it local machine.

To do this I use a WideImage.

```
<?php 

include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'libraries/wideimage/index.php');

include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'query.php');    


do { 


wideImage::load($row_getImages['remote'])->resize(360, 206, 'outside')->saveToFile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$row_getImages['local']);}

while ($row_getImages = mysql_fetch_assoc($getImages)); 


?>
```

This works most of the time. But it has a fatal flaw.

If for some reason one of these images is not available or doesn't exists.
Wideimage throws a fatal error. Preventing any further images that may exist from downloading.

I have tried checking file exists like this

```
    do { 

if(file_exists($row_getImages['remote'])){

    wideImage::load($row_getImages['remote'])->resize(360, 206, 'outside')->saveToFile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$row_getImages['local']);}

}        
    while ($row_getImages = mysql_fetch_assoc($getImages));
```

But this doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong??

Thanks

Comment: Why does the `file_exists()` check work and how is `$row_getImages` defined?

Comment: $row_getImages is defined in query.php which is included. file_exists() doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: Not sure what happen to answer that mentioned "try" and "catch" but it worked. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Can you add your try and catch solution to your post so others can benefit from it too?

Answer (score 5):

According to [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php), file_exists cannot check for remote files.   Someone suggested there, in the comments, that they use fopen as a workaround:

```
<?php
function fileExists($path){
    return (@fopen($path,"r")==true);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check via CURL:

```
$curl = curl_init('http://example.com/my_image.jpg');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($curl);
if($httpcode < 400) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Not working. Always "$httpcode" is less than 400, file exists or not does not. Very bad post.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging around the net I decided on requesting the HTTP headers, instead of a CURL request, as apparently it's less overhead.

This is an adaption of Nick's comment from the PHP forums at:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php

```
function get_http_response_code($theURL) {
   $headers = get_headers($theURL);
   return substr($headers[0], 9, 3);
}
$URL = htmlspecialchars($postURL);
$statusCode = intval(get_http_response_code($URL));

if($statusCode == 200) { // 200 = ok
    echo '<img src="'.htmlspecialchars($URL).'" alt="Image: '.htmlspecialchars($URL).'" />';
} else {
    echo '<img src="/Img/noPhoto.jpg" alt="This remote image link is broken" />';
}
```

Nick calls this function "a quick and nasty solution", although it is working well for me :-)